# Full-text search index across columns and tables

Tags: postgresql, index, json, full-text-search

I am building a document database and I would like to utilize the full-text search capabilities of PostgreSQL. The documents do not all follow a clean schema, so I decided to store some values in columnar format, but also pack the columns plus everything that does not fit into JSONB. Something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE document(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    content JSONB,
    content_tsv TSVECTOR
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS (jsonb_to_tsvector('english', content, '["string", "numeric"]')) STORED
);

CREATE INDEX ON document USING gin (content_tsv);

CREATE TABLE topic(
    name TEXT,
    description TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE document_topic(
    document_id REFERENCES document(id),
    topic REFERENCES topic(name),
    PRIMARY KEY (document_id, topic)
);
```

When indexing items, the application side handles packing the columnar data (like `title` here), the related data from other tables (like `topic` here) and unstructured extra information (like: abstract, summary, blurb, text extracted from file, etc.) into the `content` column. Users are exposed to filtering on the columns like `topic` via the relational part of the database, and to full-text searches on *all* of the content using `websearch_to_tsquery` on the `JSONB` column so they don't have to worry about which field to address specifically.

The search works very well, but it is extremely tedious to manage the `content` column when updating data across multiple relational tables, or to expose the user to whatever might have ended up in that bag of text.

At the moment I am considering pulling some information back out of the `JSONB` column and into relational columns. I am interested in whether there is a good way to automatically 'pack' other columns from across tables into a single full-text column like this. Something like a `GENERATED` column which uses a subquery (which they cannot), or a view which gathers columns from across multiple tables and runs `to_tsvector` on them, but which can be stored and indexed. Am I on the right track here? What is the best practice?